# Send Lexical data to a server and read it with a new lexical component

Tags: reactjs, lexical

this is my first time asking a question with stackoverflow, but I'm stuck on this problem for too many days.

**My question, how can I change the initialConfig.editorState to the stringifiedEditorState that I just save in my database?**

So far, I'm using Lexical, a Facebook text editor with React/Next.js. I was able to create an editor and save it to my mongodb database as a JSON string.

```
    {
   "root": {
      "children": [
         {
            "children": [
               { "detail": 0, "format": 1, "mode": "normal", "style": "", "text": "Test", "type": "text", "version": 1 }
            ],
            "direction": "ltr",
            "format": "",
            "indent": 0,
            "type": "paragraph",
            "version": 1
         }
      ],
      "direction": "ltr",
      "format": "",
      "indent": 0,
      "type": "root",
      "version": 1
   }
}
```

I want to be able to read the Json value that I save to my mongodb database with a new read only lexical editor.

```
function onChange(editorState: any) {
      editorState.read(() => {
         const stringifiedEditorState = JSON.stringify(editorState.toJSON());
         setValue(stringifiedEditorState);
      });
   }


const initialConfig = {
      namespace: "editeurConfig",
      theme: editeurTheme,
      onError: onError,
      nodes: [ListNode, ListItemNode, AutoLinkNode, LinkNode],
      readOnly: true,
      editorState: null
   };
```

**My question again, how can I change the initialConfig.editorState to the stringifiedEditorState that I just save in my database?**

Answer (score 4):

### On editor initialization

You can simply pass the serialized string into the initial state of the editor via the `editorState` key.

For example:

```js
// your config
const editorConfig = {
  // the rest of your config...
  editorState: editorStateJSONString,
};

// inside your return statement
<LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
   {/* Your plugins */}
</LexicalComposer>
```

The caveat is that:

> Note that Lexical uses initialConfig.editorState only once (when it's
> being initialized) and passing different value later won't be
> reflected in editor

From: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/editor-state

So it depends on the timing of initializing the editor and when you retrieve the database data.

### After editor initialization

It appears you can use `setEditorState` to update state after initialization:

> Another way to set state is setEditorState method, which replaces
> current state with the one passed as an argument.

For example:

```js
const editorState = editor.parseEditorState(editorStateJSONString);
editor.setEditorState(editorState);
```

From: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/editor-state#updating-state

For more details see: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/editor-state

Comment: Thank you so much, it work perfectly. I just had to put the stringifiedEditorState value inside a `` and to add readOnly= true to the new component readOnlyLexicalComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the onChange Plugin as follows

import the packages

```
import { createEditor } from 'lexical';
import { $generateHtmlFromNodes } from '@lexical/html';
import { $convertToMarkdownString, TRANSFORMERS } from '@lexical/markdown';
import { OnChangePlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalOnChangePlugin';
```

Now use the plugin inside LexicalComposer

```
<OnChangePlugin
        onChange={(editorState) => {
          editorState.read(() => {
            const config: any = {
              namespace: 'Temp',
              theme: editorConfig.theme,
              nodes: editorConfig.nodes,
              onError: editorConfig.onError,
              editable: true,
              editorState: editorState,
            };

            const editor = createEditor(config);
            const htmlString = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
            const markdown = $convertToMarkdownString(TRANSFORMERS);

            // manage your useState here
          });
        }}
      />
```